# Trying to hide an element with jQuery via clicking another element on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Apologies as it has been a few years since I have done much with jquery, I am in a marketing role now but my employer really wants me to add this functionality to the site.

I am trying to have a page where I click a tab and it hides an image loaded at the top of the page. tried repurposing an old bit of code but no dice :(

JS:

```
      jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

$( ".contacttabbyheaders" ).click(function() {
    $( ".hideonclick" ).css( "display", "none" );
});
 //} /* extra, cause of breaking */
});
```

HTML:

```
<img class="hideonclick" src="https://linestar.ca/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/Map.png" alt="" width="auto" height="300px !important" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-41833" style=" margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-height: 350px" />

 <br>

 [tabby title="British Columbia" class="contacttabbyheaders"]
```

Sorry again for the bad code, I no longer do coding and don't plan on getting back into it just need this fix!!

Comment: What is `[tabby]`? That's not HTML. Is there something that converts that to an HTML element?

Comment: It is a wp-plugin (I think it would be defined as shortcode) but I am able to css select the class to efect the element via CSS so I thought it should be valid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have defined two classes in img tag merge them

```html
<img class="hideonclick aligncenter size-full wp-image-41833" 
     src="https://linestar.ca/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/Map.png" alt="" 
     width="auto" height="300px !important" 
     style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-height: 350px" />
```

Comment: I have fixed but still no cigar :( here is the page if that helps:

Comment: https://linestar.ca/cpn/

Comment: the element "contacttabbyheaders" is hidden thats why you can not remove the image, you want to click on the state items and remove the image of the map ?

Comment: Yes correct, so when I click on any of the 6 state buttons it will hide the img of the map

Comment: ok, change ".contacttabbyheaders" to ".responsive-tabs__list__item" in your code and test it

Comment: That works! Only thing now is for some reason it is duplicating the tabs (top version original bottom version is the working version) viewable on the webpage link. Any ideas why that is happening? Massively appreciate your help!

Comment: the 2 duplicated data are for responsive view and I dont know how they got the class ".responsive-tabs__list__item" if you can edit the responsive tabs remove this class from them
and change ".responsive-tabs__list__item" to "li..responsive-tabs__list__item" in your js code

Comment: Ok I will play around with it thanks so much!